# Echo command without moving to a new line and continuing on the previous line in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following code tries to write the hashes of all .rgsp files in a tree, to a text file:

```bash
for /r %%A in (*.rsgp) do (
    echo | set /p="%%A * "
    certutil -hashfile %%A MD5 | find /v "h"
) >> file.txt
```

The output result in the text file will look like this:

```
filename * hash
```

However, what I want to do is to output it in a different order:

```
hash * filename
```

I did try putting `echo|set /p="%%A * "` after the `certutil` command, but that still won't work as the `echo` will write the filename still before hash for some reason but it ignores the first line in the text file, like this:

```
hash
filename * hash
filename * hash
...
```

How can I make the `echo` command write the filename right after the hash is written in that very specific line in the text file, instead of first filename and then hash?

Let me know If I wasn't clear on some part of my question, thanks.

Comment: Catch the `certutil` output with another `for /f "delims=" %%B ...` loop and echo `%%A %%B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be used for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /R %%I in (*.rsgp) do for /F "delims=" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -hashfile "%%I" MD5 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "h"') do echo %%J * %%I)>"files.txt"
endlocal
```

The file names are written into the output file `files.txt` with fully qualified file name because of the usage of the **FOR** option `/R` results in searching recursive in the **current** directory (not necessarily the batch file directory) and all its subdirectories for non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `*.rsgp` in long or short file name with assigning the file name with full path to the loop variable `I`. There can be used the option `%%~nxI` instead of `%%I` at end of the command line to write only file name + file extension into the output file `files.txt`. **FOR** would assign only the file name with file extension without full path to the loop variable `I` on omitting the **FOR** option `/R` to search only in the current directory for non-hidden `.rsgp` files.

The batch file above can result in having spaces in the MD5 hash value depending on which version of `certutil.exe` is used depending on version of Windows.

This variant of above writes the MD5 hash value into the output file without a space between the hexadecimal values of each byte of the hash value independent on which version of `certutil.exe` is executed by the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /R %%# in (*.rsgp) do for /F "tokens=1-16" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -hashfile "%%#" MD5 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "h"') do echo %%G%%H%%I%%J%%K%%L%%M%%N%%O%%P%%Q%%R%%S%%T%%U%%V * %%#)>"files.txt"
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `certutil -?`
- `certutil -hashfile -?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `|`. The redirection operator `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` with the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.