# Need assistance creating a batch file that will calculate the md5 checksum of a given filepath and output that to a txt document

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have gotten the basic command to work for one file using the filepath and output the result to a txt doc.

Ideally, I would like to create a loop that will calculate the MD5 checksum for each file/filepath listed in a txt doc named "filepathlist.txt"

I am not familiar with the windows command utilities enough to get a loop working.

Here is what I have

```
certutil - hashfile C:\pathtofile\file.xml MD5 >> md5checksums.txt
```

Which outputs

```
MD5 hash of C:\pathofile\file.xml:
8c2ad3e4ddd931a456ff1c45c3d294ad2
```

As previously stated, I have a txt document that lists the file paths for all of the files I need a checksum for. Is there some way to loop this command so that it will run through all of the files and then output the Path and hash value on the same line?

I would like the output to look like this

```
C:\pathoffile\file.xml 8c2ad3e4ddd931a456ff1c45c3d294ad2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple questions here (looping through a file that lists filename and performing an operation on each one, and how to parse the output of certutil), which should be in separate posts. For the first one, type `for /?` at a command prompt and read the help content that you'll see there. For the second, search this site, as parsing output in a batch file has been asked and answered multiple times here.

Comment: See my answer on [Echo command without moving to a new line and continuing on the previous line in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76907877/3074564) and replace `for /R %%I in (*.rsgp) do` by `for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("filepathlist.txt") do` in the batch file with just four command lines.

Comment: Checkout: [HASHSUM.BAT v1.8 - emulate md5sum, shasum, and the like](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get certutil to output just the md5-Hash. The hash will be written in the second line of the `md5checksums.txt` file. Therefor a little helper loop is required to get the second line from the file. Maybe someone knows how to solve this issue. Couldn't find anything about that with `certutil -?`, but maybe have a deeper look. But as [@Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) pointed out, that maybe is not possible.

---

Put the files as list in a file like this. Absolute or relative path. Quotation marks are optional, they will be removed in the script later on. If you can make sure that all path are with or without quotation marks you can do so and alter the batch script accordingly.

`yourFileList.txt`

```
C:\absolute\path\with whitespace\testFile1.txt
testFile2.txt
"testFile3.txt"
test File4.txt
"C:\some\other\path\testFile5.txt"
```

Alter your batch file as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM absolute or relative paths to the input and output files
SET "inputFileList=C:\path\with whitespace\yourFileList.txt"
SET "md5File=md5checksums.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%inputFileList%") do (
    SET "fileToBeChecked=%%a"
    
    REM The following will remove " in the file from the list. 
    REM Thus making sure that the strings are uniform
    REM You can remove this line if all paths in the list are without quotation marks
    SET fileToBeChecked=!fileToBeChecked:"=!
    
    IF EXIST "!fileToBeChecked!" (
        certutil -hashfile "!fileToBeChecked!" MD5>%md5File%

        REM Read the second line from the generated File. That is where the hash is placed.
        FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G IN ('findstr /n "^" %md5File%') DO IF %%G EQU 2 SET md5Result=%%H
        
        ECHO !fileToBeChecked! !md5Result!
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO !fileToBeChecked! File not found.
    )
)

REM If you don't need the help file md5checksums.txt you can do so
DEL %md5File%

PAUSE
```

Result:

```
C:\absolute\path\with whitespace\testFile1.txt 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
testFiel2.txt 81b073de9370ea873f548e31b8adc081
...
```

**Note 1:** There will be an error message if a file is empty. You should check that, if this is a possible situation.
**Note 2:** It would be possible to put all the ECHOed lines in a second results file and `TYPE` the file to stdout at the end

Comment: Thank you. I have used this with my current test folder and replaced with the correct names, however, I am now getting this error in the output file.

Expected no more than 2 args, recieved 3
CertUtil: Too many arguments

I have been to change a few things and move that around but I am still getting that error.

Comment: Do you have a whitespace char in your file path? Make sure that there are quotation marks `"` around the path. I will add them in my answer later on. They should always be placed around paths. I forgot.

Comment: Oh my gosh that was it I forgot the quotes in the test file list. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a solution for the whitespace problem.